# How to solve Mathematical Expressions in Rails 4 like 6000*70%?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, calculator

I am using [Dentaku gem](https://github.com/rubysolo/dentaku) to solve little complex expressions like basic salary is 70% of Gross salary. As the formulas are user editable so I worked on dentaku.

When I write `calculator = Dentaku::Calculator.new` to initialize and then enter the command `calculator.evaluate("60000*70%")` then error comes like below:

```
Dentaku::ParseError: Dentaku::AST::Modulo requires numeric operands
from /Users/sulman/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/dentaku-2.0.8/lib/dentaku/ast/arithmetic.rb:11:in `initialize'
```

I have array is which formula is stored like: `["EarningItem-5","*","6","7","%"]` where EarningItem-5 is an object and has value 60000

How can I resolve such expressions?

Comment: For this particular case you can use
`basic_salary = gross_salary * 0.7`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this particular case you can use `basic_salary = gross_salary * 0.7`

Next you need to create the number field in your views which accepts `0..100` range. At last, set up the after_save callback and use this code:

**model**

```
after_create :percent_to_float

protected

def percent_to_float
  self.percent = percent / 100.0
  self.save
end
```

**edit:**
Of course, you can simply use this formula without any callbacks:

```
basic_salary = gross_salary / 100.0 * 70
```

where 70 is user defined value.

Comment: data is coming like `["EarningItem-5","*","6","7","%"]` so user can enter 670% as well

Comment: For me your formula is like magic :) 
Can you interpret it?
ps: feel free to define your own range or just omit it

Comment: Did It help you? Any feedback? It's quite frustrating =\

Answer (score 1):

Dentaku does not appear to support "percent". Try this instead

```
calculator.evaluate('60000 * 0.7')
```

Comment: user can enter 70%... How to solve that??? Or how I can change 70% or any other percent to point values?

Comment: if the user enters 70 you can convert that to 0.7 by dividing by 100.            70 / 100.0 = 0.7

Comment: data is coming like `["EarningItem-5","*","6","7","%"]` so user can enter 670% as well